# Sysmalloc Assertion Error, Computing Two's Compliment

Tags: c, memory, malloc, assertion

I have written a C Program which converts two decimal number to a binary arrays and also calculates its two's compliments. Here's the program:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

// Function for calculating the optimal size of the binary array
int getOptimalBinarySize(int number1, int number2)
{
    int size = 0;

    if(number1 < 0 || number2 < 0)
    {
        size++;
    }

    number1 = abs(number1);
    number2 = abs(number2);

    if(number1 > number2)
    {
        size += log(number1)/log(2) + 1 + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        size += log(number2)/log(2) + 1 + 1;
    }

    return size;
}

// Function takes an integer and an optimal size 
// that creates a dynamically allocated array
// of the given size and fills it with the binary representation
// of the given integer then which returns the pointer
// to that array.

int* getBinaryArray(int number, int size)
{
    int* binary_array = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    int i = size-1;

    while(number)
    {
        binary_array[i] = number % 2;
        number /= 2;
        i--;
    }
    
    while(i >= 0)
    {
        binary_array[i] = 0;
        i--;
    }
    
    return binary_array;
}

//Function takes two binary arrays and a size which calculates the sum
// and returns a pointer to that sum array which is dynamically allocated

int* addTwoBinaryArrays(int* binary_array1, int* binary_array2, int size)
{
    int* sum_binary_array = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    int carry = 0, ith_index_sum = 0;

    while(size >= 0)
    {   
        ith_index_sum = binary_array1[size] + binary_array2[size] + carry;

        if(ith_index_sum == 3)
        {
            sum_binary_array[size] = 1;
        }
        else if(ith_index_sum == 2)
        {
            sum_binary_array[size] = 0;

            if(carry == 0)
                carry = 1;

        }
        else if(ith_index_sum == 1)
        {
            sum_binary_array[size] = 1;

            if(carry == 1)
                carry = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            sum_binary_array[size] = 0;
        }

        size--;
    }

    return sum_binary_array;
}

//Function take a binary array and a size
// and returns a pointer to the dynamically allocated
// array of the two's Compliment of the given array

int* getTwosCompliment(int* number_binary, int size)
{
    int ones_compliment[size];

    for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
    {
        if(number_binary[i] == 0)
            ones_compliment[i] = 1;
        else
            ones_compliment[i] = 0;
    }

    int onein_binary[size];

    for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
        onein_binary[i] = 0;

    onein_binary[size-1] = 1;

    return addTwoBinaryArrays(ones_compliment, onein_binary, size);
}


int main()
{
    printf("Enter two integers:-\n");
    int number1 = 0, number2 = 0;
    scanf("%d%d", &number1, &number2);
    
    int size = getOptimalBinarySize(number1, number2);
    
    
    int* number1_binary = getBinaryArray(abs(number1), size);
    int* number2_binary = getBinaryArray(abs(number2), size);
    
    printf("Calculated Optimal Size: %d\n", size);
    
    int* number1_twos_compliment = getTwosCompliment(number1_binary, size);
    int* number2_twos_compliment = getTwosCompliment(number2_binary, size);
    
    printf("\nNumbers in binary:-\n");
    for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", number1_binary[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", number2_binary[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\nTwos Compliment of the numbers in binary:-\n");
    for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", number1_twos_compliment[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", number2_twos_compliment[i]);
    }
}
```

I have been testing this program for a while and found that it works fine if both the given integers are positive and also for a few cases when one integer is negative like:-
(These are random inputs which works fine)

7 -6

5 -2

-5 4

But for some inputs like:- (Inputs for which I get error)

8 -1

9 -6

It gives me this error:

```
malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
```

I figured this much out that the problem is when I call for twosCompliment, but I don't get it why

Please help
Thanks

Comment: If you allocate `size` items then `array[size]` is out of bounds. Indices are zero-based and the valid ones are 0 to size -1. You have a buffer overflow no matter the input, but luckily you've found some where it's fatal so you know your program is broken. https://godbolt.org/z/x1KM3bWqf

Comment: Oh my bad, Yes I got it, I forgot to decrease the size by one in the addTwoBinaryArrays function before using it to access the elements.

Thanks a lot for figuring out this for me